# Complex type passed by aura component to apex method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, parameters, apex-param, inner-class

we have this inner class:

```
public class Documents {
    @AuraEnabled public String type;
    @AuraEnabled public List<Custom_Document__c> documents;
}
```

And we use it in a method declared like this:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateCase(Id caseId, List<Documents> documents) {
          ...
    }
```

We invoke the method from an aura component in this way:

```
helper.invokeRemoteAction(component, "updateCase", {caseId: component.get("v.caseId"), documents: component.get("v.documents")})
```

where `invokeRemoteAction` is declared like this:

```
invokeRemoteAction: function(component, actionName, params) {
        const action = component.get("c." + actionName);
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            action.setParams(params);
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                else if (response.getState() === "ERROR") reject(response.getError());
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        });
    }
```

The problem is that the first parameter is OK but second `List<Documents> documents` is always `null`. Why?

Comment: I've used this syntax before successfully, so it's hard to tell given the information we have here. Make sure the attribute is an array, and each element has an attribute `sobjectType: 'ITA_IFM_Document__c'`. This is the most common reason why code like this would fail, given everything else looks correct.

Comment: It doesn't work but I think I don't understand well. Could you write an example as answer, please? Thanks.